# Pushing my rails app to heroku problems with yml config files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, yaml, config

I am very new to Heroku. I am trying to push my app in production.

I receive this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/build_dcbb4827f57714285a83d2983a8816d6/config/twilio.yml
```

In my app I have a twillio.yml file where I keep my secrets for twillio:

```
development:
 from: ''
 sid: ''
 token: ''
production:
 from: ''
 sid: ''
 token: ''
```

I then tried to run

```
heroku config:set sid:*** token:*** from:***
```

But then I see this:

```
!    Usage: heroku config:set KEY1=VALUE1 [KEY2=VALUE2 ...]
!    Must specify KEY and VALUE to set.
```

Comment: how do you load twillio.yml ? What is path to it. e.g. YAML.load_file 'path/to/yaml'

Comment: Have you committed the file in GIT and pushed it to heroku?

Comment: Certainly the second error message is saying that you should be saying `heroku config:set sid=*** token=*** from=***`. You're using the wrong separator characters.

Comment: Looks like you have two separate issues going on. The `Errono` one i think we need more context. Can you paste more of the stack trace?

piggy back on gene you need to change your command to
`heroku config:set TWILLIO_KEY=TWLLIO_SECRET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your .gitignore file ? It is possible that the temp directory is in .gitignore.
All the directories or files, listed in .gtignore will not be uploaded to heroku. Therefore there is error "**Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory**"

Comment: Yes ive got application.yml and twillio.yml in .gitignore... so before pushing on heroku I should delete this file from the .gitignore ?

Comment: Yes. So that this file could be uploaded to Heroku.

Comment: after deleting from .gitignore you should run the following commands :
             git add .     ==>    git commit -m "delete from .gitignore" ===> then git push master heroku